# What is the Laplace transformation of $x(2t)$?

Tags: laplace-transform

I know that $x(2t) = \frac12x(t)$. What is the Laplace transformation of  $x(2t)$? Can you show all steps?

$$
\begin{align}
X(s) &= \int_{-\infty}^{+\infty} x(2t)e^{-st}\,\,dt \\
     &= \frac12\int_{-\infty}^{+\infty} x(t)e^{-st}\,\,dt\\
     &= ?
\end{align}
$$

Comment: Hey, you should type up what you have tried so that we know how to help you + don't just do your homework for you

Comment: i just added what i know of.

Comment: The definition you're using of Laplace transform is wrong.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Definition of Laplace transform is

$$
\mathcal{L}[x](s) = \int_{0}^{+\infty} x(t)e^{-st}dt = X(s).
$$

If $a>0$ and $\left(S_{a}x\right)(t)=x(at)$ we have

$$
\mathcal{L}[S_ax](s) = \int_{0}^{+\infty} \left( S_a x \right)(t)e^{-st}dt = \int_{0}^{+\infty} x(at)e^{-st}dt = \frac{1}{a}\int_{0}^{+\infty} x(t)e^{-\frac{s}{a}t}dt = \frac{1}{a}\left(S_{\frac{1}{a}} X\right)(s) = \frac{1}{a} X\left(\frac{s}{a}\right),
$$

which means the operator $S_a$ is mapped into $\frac{1}{a} S_\frac{1}{a}$. Therefore if $x(t)$ is transformed into $X(s)$ then $x(2t)$ will be transformed into $\frac{1}{2} X\left( \frac{s}{2}\right)$. But you also have $x(2t) = \frac{1}{2} x(t)$ hence you have the identity

$$
\frac{1}{2} X\left(\frac{s}{2}\right) = \frac{1}{2} X(s) \Rightarrow X\left(\frac{s}{2}\right) = X(s).
$$

You can easily derive the recurrence

$$
X\left( \frac{s}{2^k} \right) = X(s)
$$

and for $k \to +\infty$ you have

$$
X(0) = X(s)
$$

which means the Laplace transform of your function is a constant, more specifically

$$
\mathcal{L}[x](s) = \int_{0}^{+\infty} x(t)dt
$$

For the recurrence:

$$
X(s) = X\left(\frac{s}{2}\right) = X\left(\frac{s}{2^2}\right) = \ldots = X\left(\frac{s}{2^k}\right)
$$

For the continuity:

Let $s_k$ be a sequence such that $|s_k| \to 0$, we have

$$
\lim_{k \to \infty} X(s_k) = \lim_{k \to \infty} \int_{0}^{+\infty} x(t)e^{-s_kt} dt = \int_{0}^{+\infty} x(t) \left(\lim_{k \to \infty} e^{-s_k t} \right) dt = \int_{0}^{+\infty} x(t) dt = X(0),
$$

of course this works if $X(0)$ exists.

Comment: Could you add how you came up with the recurrence?

Comment: The $X\left(\frac{s}{2}\right) = X(s)$?

Comment: I meant $X(s/2^k)=X(s)$

Comment: Added, but it's essentially re-iterating the equality, nothing fancy.

Comment: Yeah indeed, but for the next argument to work you’d need some sort of continuity, at least in 0. Is this valid in general for Laplace transforms?

Comment: What assumptions do you have on your $x(t)$? Just being in $L^1$ loc?

Comment: @user190080 My apologies... I thought you were the OP xD. If you can explain your trick that would be great.

Comment: I guess anyway something can be inferred using $$\left\lvert X(0) -
 X(s) \right\rvert = \left\lvert \int_{0}^{+\infty} x(t)(1 - e^{-st}) dt \right\rvert,$$ also exploiting that for $s\to 0$ we have $1 - e^{-st} = st + o(|s|)$

Comment: By the way, the solution of the recurrence is the same for all $s$

Comment: That's true, but without knowing anything about the transforms continuity we can't conclude that this implies that $X(s)$ is constant. One can construct a function for which $f(x)=f(x/2)$ doesn't imply that $f$ is constant (ofc $f$ isn't continuous then here)

Comment: Ok, but assume that $X(0)$ does exist, then if you pick any convergent sequence $s_k \to 0$ you have $$\lim_{k\to \infty} X(s_k) = \int_{0}^{\infty} x(t) e^{s_k t} dt = \int_{0}^{\infty} x(t) \left(\lim_{k \to \infty} e^{-st} \right) dt = \int_{0}^{+\infty} x(t) dt = X(0)$$ because the sequence is arbitrary this implies continuity in $0$

Comment: You can argue above whether or not I can bring the limit under the integral sign. But I guess I can do that if $X(0)$ exists.

Comment: Looks good already...if we now assume that $x(t)\in L^1$ then we could apply the dominated convergence theorem and interchange limit and integration.

Comment: Yep, that's exactly what I was thinking (I made a bit of a mess with my formula above).

Comment: I guess this answers the question then, nice work (maybe it's possible to weaken the assumptions but $L^1$ suffices then).

Comment: I guess/hope it does, I'm a damn engineer, so usually I miss some of the subtleties xD.

Comment: If I understand correctly, Lf = const. should imply $f$ is a multiple of the dirac mass at 0 and so cannot be an 'integrable function' unless $f=0$.

Comment: but the dirac function is integrable right, I mean the laplace transform does exist as a distribution?

Comment: @CalvinKhor good point, but by definition we have ${\displaystyle \int _{-\infty }^{\infty }\delta (x)\,dx=1}$ which should make it suitable for the DCT approach - although not as a function of $L^1$ ofc

Comment: yeah well, DCT with dirac measure is convergence at 0 :) Just wanted to point out the reverse implication that if $Lx = \int_0^\infty x(t) dt$ then we can exploit the symmetry
$$  \int_0^\infty x(t)\ dt = \int_{\{0\}}x(t)dt + \sum_{k\in\mathbb Z}^\infty \int_{(2^k,2^{k+1}]} x(t)  \ dt =  \sum_{k\in\mathbb Z} \int_{(1,2]} x(2^kt') 2^{k}\ dt'$$ where $t=2^kt'$, and the symmetry $x(2t) = \frac12 x(t)$ perfectly cancels the $2^k$s, 
$$ \int_0^\infty x(t)\ dt = \int_{\{0\}} x(t) \ dt + \sum_{k\in\mathbb Z} \int_{(1,2]} x(t) \ dt$$
so  $\int_{(1,2]} x(t) \ dt=0$ and any function $x$ must be $0$.